# Load multiple json files in Python and in these files check if the key 'description' has a value which is string and non-empty

Tags: python, json, key-value

Trying the following code, but it returns all the files which does not have the key 'description'

```
for filename in glob.glob('*.json'):
    with open(filename, "r") as read_file:
        data = json.load(read_file)
        if  (data.get('description') is None):
            print("the description is none" , filename)
```

Comment: What did you *want* it to do?

Comment: `if data.get('description'):`